# aspect ratio of image crashing the program

Tags: c, windows, winapi, preview-pane

here is the code this code is to maintain the aspect ratio of the image it crashes when the control goes to   int WindowRatio = WidthOfPreviewPane / HeightOfPreviewPane;
 can anyone give idea why ??

```
int WidthOfPreviewPane = RECTWIDTH(m_rcParent); 
int HeightOfPreviewPane = RECTHEIGHT(m_rcParent) ; 

int ImageRatio = WidthOfImage / HeightOfImage;
int WindowRatio = WidthOfPreviewPane / HeightOfPreviewPane;

if (WindowRatio > ImageRatio && WidthOfPreviewPane< WidthOfImage)
{
    m_iFinalHeight = HeightOfPreviewPane;
    m_iFinalWidth = m_iFinalHeight * ImageRatio;
    MessageBox(NULL, L"1",L"Error", 
            MB_ICONERROR | MB_OK);
}
else if (WindowRatio < ImageRatio && WidthOfPreviewPane< WidthOfImage)
{
    m_iFinalWidth = WidthOfPreviewPane;
    m_iFinalHeight = m_iFinalWidth / ImageRatio;
        MessageBox(NULL, L"2",L"Error", 
            MB_ICONERROR | MB_OK);
}
else if(WindowRatio > ImageRatio && WidthOfPreviewPane> WidthOfImage)
{
    m_iFinalHeight = HeightOfImage;
    m_iFinalWidth = WidthOfImage;
        MessageBox(NULL, L"3",L"Error", 
            MB_ICONERROR | MB_OK);

}
else if(WindowRatio < ImageRatio && WidthOfPreviewPane> WidthOfImage)
{
    m_iFinalHeight = HeightOfImage;
    m_iFinalWidth = WidthOfImage;
        MessageBox(NULL, L"4",L"Error", 
            MB_ICONERROR | MB_OK);

}
```

Comment: Assuming windows? Have you tried to run the code in the debugger? Is the window (m_rcParent) visible, otherwise the size is 0 causing a devisionbyzero

Comment: check to see what the value of `HeightOfPreviewPane` is before the problem line is run

Comment: is `HeightOfPreviewPane` `0`? check it.

Comment: yes it WidthOfPreviewPane and HeightOfPreviewPane both are zero ..how it is possible my preview pane is fully open..

Comment: yes the algo is absolutey correct there was a little problem because i had to set window position..it is solved by if(WidthOfPreviewPane!= 0 && HeightOfPreviewPane!=0 ) which ony let the cursor go inside when the condition is correct.that was a big help anniekim

Answer (score 0):

the logic of this algo is correct finally i found that WidthOfPreviewPane and HeightOfPreviewPane=0 its because the function in which i have written this code was initialized at last so these 2 were not initialized that time when i debugged them and i avoided thid problem by putting them in in a if condition which will let the control go inside if their value is not 0 and it worked nicely.
see this-

```
 if(WidthOfPreviewPane!= 0 && HeightOfPreviewPane!=0 )
            {
                  conditions here......

            }
```

and thats solved.